# Add or remove hours to timestamp while select

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have timestamp stored in utc in format "2017-08-25 14:34:20.0000000 +00:00". Our customer selects timestamps directly from db and they want to add additional hours in order to fit timestamp stored with their timezone. Can I set a select query to make it to add hours to current timestamp? Database sql-server

Comment: I mean, we store timezones in utc +0 , they want it in utc +6. I want selecting timezone set query in way to add six hours. For example, "2017-08-25 14:34:20.0000000 +00:00"  would become "2017-08-25 20:34:20.0000000 +00:00"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would help:

The DATEADD() function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

DATEADD(interval, number, date)

> interval  Required. The time/date part to return. Can be one of the
> following values:
>
> - year, yyyy, yy = Year quarter,
> - qq, q = Quarter month,
> - mm, m = month
> - dayofyear = Day of the year day,  dy,
> - y = Day
> - week, ww, wk = Week
> - weekday, dw, w = Weekday
> - hour, hh = hour
> - minute, mi, n = Minute
> - second, ss, s = Second
> - millisecond, ms = Millisecond
>
> number    Required. The number of intervals to use
>
> date  Required. The date to which the interval should be added

DATEADD(HOUR,1,fieldFromSQL)

Answer (score 1):

I find the new command "AT TIME ZONE" very useful for this.
This requires SQL Server 2016 sp1.
Here is how:

```
DECLARE @FieldFromSQL DATETIME2= GETUTCDATE()
SELECT @FieldFromSQL AS DateTimeInUTC , @FieldFromSQL 
     AT TIME ZONE 'utc' 
     AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' AS DateTimeInLocalTime
```

It also works across Daylight time changes, with which I've had many problems.